Build a new command "newsymbol" with NewDocumentCommand
I want to create a new command \newsymbol, which functions like \newcommand, but with the difference that math is ensured. I also have another reason, why I want to define this new command, namely so that I can recognize in my own code, where I defined a new symbol of my own doing instead of any other type of command. There is a certain "class" of symbols that I want to mark this way if you will. Anyway; this is what I have come up with, but it does not work, as  I get the error that unknownSpace is not defined.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % Required for defining commands with optional arguments

    % Define \newsymbol using xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\newsymbol}{s m o o m}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \IfNoValueTF{#3}{
            \IfNoValueTF{#4}{
                \expandafter\newcommand*\csname #2\endcsname[#3][#4]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }{
                \expandafter\newcommand*\csname #2\endcsname[#3]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }
        }{
                \expandafter\newcommand*\csname #2\endcsname{\ensuremath{#5}}
        }
    }{
        \IfNoValueTF{#3}{
            \IfNoValueTF{#4}{
                \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname[#3][#4]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }{
                \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname[#3]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }
        }{
                \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname{\ensuremath{#5}}
        }
    }
}

% Example usage
\newsymbol{unknownSpace}[1]{X_#1}
\newsymbol{unknownSpaceR}[1][u]{V_{#1}}

\begin{document}

% Using the new commands
$\unknownSpace{1}$
$\unknownSpace{2}$
$\unknownSpaceR$
$\unknownSpaceR[3]$

\end{document}


EDIT: I have tried a lot of ideas. For example, for the solution by egreg, I get


Having commands for your own mathematical objects is a great idea, but what you describe doesn’t sound like the right approach to me, for several reasons: (1) Building \ensuremath into commands is tempting until you realize how nice it is that math is actually marked as math in your code, using $...$ or \(...\). (2) This interface of defining many commands in one go looks complicated and is likely to make your syntax all the more confusing. And (3) you will have to set up custom syntax highlighting if you want your editor to recognize your commands.

You've got some expansion issues. For one thing, TeX reads #1 in the second argument and complains because it's not in the replacement text of a command definition (yet). Same with the _ and math mode. I'm not sure how to tell xparse to defer expansion.

And when you do \expandafter\newcommand*\csname #2\endcsname{\ensuremath{#5}}, this \expandafter will expand the * rather than the \csname. You need something like \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname #2\endcsname{\ensuremath{#5}}.

@Gaussler: Regarding (1) to (3) in your first comment: Maybe we misunderstand each other. What I currently have is, for example, \newcommand{\featureSpace}[1][F]\ensuremath{\mathbb{\MakeUppercase{R}}^{#1}}. But it is much more complex for me, because I would first define a style for infinite sets, then say that a "realnumbers" is an infinite set with based on R as base symbol, then put that as a symbol into "featureSpace". In fact there is a whole system build by me and I am using this for more then 10 years now for my papers, theses, and now for my dissertation.

This system has served me very well. My newest idea (in my questions) changes nothing in the way I would use the symbols in my main text. I understood you such that you prefer to type the literals like "x" or "\beta" out in the main body of the text. But maybe you mean something different altogether. (As a side note, to give an idea, why I do this: I have used up all the latin and greek alphabet in my more than 200 pages dissertation and I regularly need to change the symbols and idea during the development of my ideas. Programming everything, makes swapping symbols and notation trivial.)

@Make42 I don’t disagree. My own math is typed using my package semantex which is built around the same idea.

Please copy-past messages and code as plain text so it can be accessed by screen-readers (and indexed and searched).

@cfr: That is not possible with my editor kile. I would have had to type everything out. And in this case, this did not seem to be worth the effort, as my screenshot is - at best - an adage.

@Make42 Sorry, but that is complete rubbish. I use Kile myself and there is absolutely no problem. Run compilation in the terminal 'part` (at the bottom) so that it stops at the first error. Or just open the log file and copy from there. The 'output' tab should also be copyable in most cases.

@cfr: The "Output" window allows for copy-pasting, true. But the in "Log and Messages", the "Messages" window only show clickable links (that bring me to the issue in my code). Are you able to copy from the "Messages" window?

@Make42 No, but the 'Log and Messages' is typically less useful to paste here anyway because it rarely gives complete messages. It is true that it filters out some unnecessary stuff, but people reading your questions will skip that stuff anyhow. The context of the messages is generally meaningful. The summary is usually useful only if I know what the problem is and just need to figure out where. (E.g. for missing cross-refs, citations etc., but not for what-the-hell-is-wrong-now problems.)

I can’t say I like this syntax, but
\documentclass{article}

    % Define \newsymbol using xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\newsymbol}{s m o o m}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \IfValueTF{#3}{
            \IfValueTF{#4}{
                \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname #2\endcsname[#3][#4]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }{
                \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname #2\endcsname[#3]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }
        }{
                \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname #2\endcsname{\ensuremath{#5}}
        }
    }{
        \IfValueTF{#3}{
            \IfValueTF{#4}{
                \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname[#3][#4]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }{
                \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname[#3]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }
        }{
                \expandafter\newcommand\csname #2\endcsname{\ensuremath{#5}}
        }
    }
}

% Example usage
\newsymbol{unknownSpace}[1]{X_{#1}}
\newsymbol{unknownSpaceR}[1][u]{V_{#1}}

\begin{document}

% Using the new commands
$\unknownSpace{1}$
$\unknownSpace{2}$
$\unknownSpaceR$
$\unknownSpaceR[3]$

\end{document}


If you absolutely must define the commands using your own version of \newcommand, why not make life easier for yourself by doing it this way instead?
\documentclass{article}

    % Define \newsymbol using xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\newsymbol}{s m o o m}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \IfValueTF{#3}{
            \IfValueTF{#4}{
                \newcommand*#2[#3][#4]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }{
                \newcommand*#2[#3]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }
        }{
                \newcommand*#2{\ensuremath{#5}}
        }
    }{
        \IfValueTF{#3}{
            \IfValueTF{#4}{
                \newcommand#2[#3][#4]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }{
                \newcommand#2[#3]{\ensuremath{#5}}
            }
        }{
                \newcommand#2{\ensuremath{#5}}
        }
    }
}

% Example usage
\newsymbol{\unknownSpace}[1]{X_{#1}}
\newsymbol{\unknownSpaceR}[1][u]{V_{#1}}

\begin{document}

% Using the new commands
$\unknownSpace{1}$
$\unknownSpace{2}$
$\unknownSpaceR$
$\unknownSpaceR[3]$

\end{document}

Or even better, just write \newcommand{\newsymbol}{\newcommand} or \let\newsymbol=\newcommand and drop the requirement that the commands should automatically wrap the output in \ensuremath.

\usepackage{xparse} % Required for defining commands with optional arguments  xparse is only needed in old latex releases

@DavidCarlisle Yeah, I actually knew that, I kinda just forgot to change it (or was too lazy). Thanks for the correction.

You have the \IfNoValueTF tests reversed: you're using the arguments in the true branch instead of the false branch.
This is cured by using \IfValueTF.
Next, \expandafter\newcommand*\csname #2\endcsname tries to expand *. This can be cured by \ExpandArgs{Nc} that also avoids \csname.
You can also give O{0} as the first optional argument, so dispensing with a test.
\documentclass{article}

% Define \newsymbol using xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\newsymbol}{s m O{0} o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
      \ExpandArgs{Nc}\newcommand*{#2}[#3][#4]{\ensuremath{#5}}%
    }{%
      \Expandargs{Nc}\newcommand*{#2}[#3]{\ensuremath{#5}}%
    }%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
      \ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{#2}[#3][#4]{\ensuremath{#5}}%
    }{%
      \ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{#2}[#3]{\ensuremath{#5}}%
    }%
  }
}

% Example usage
\newsymbol{unknownSpace}[1]{X_{#1}}
\newsymbol{unknownSpaceR}[1][u]{V_{#1}}

\begin{document}

% Using the new commands
$\unknownSpace{1}$
$\unknownSpace{2}$
$\unknownSpaceR$
$\unknownSpaceR[3]$

\end{document}

What you gain by adding \ensuremath is really disputable. I'd not use it and prefer to properly segregate math inside $...$ in any case.
I see no gain also in passing a name rather than a control sequence.


I tried your MWE, but I get the error "Undefined control sequence \newsymbol{unknownSpace}[1]{X_{#1}}" and then "Missing \begin{document} \newsymbol{unknownSpace}[1]{X_{#1}}" and "You already have nine parameters" and so on. I most a picture in my question (I can copy it from the kile output window).

@Make42 You probably have a really outdated TeX system.

That is in fact quite possible.
